# Android layouts: how to approach dynamic generated survey forms

Tags: android, forms, android-layout

I need to develop a survey application.

The user will make some choices first and then the appropriate list of questions will be shown.

Since I have a list of more then 2000 questions to choose from, it is impossible to create a XML layout for each type of survey. The idea is to iterate through a local SQLite database where the questions are stored and show only those which meet the parameters set at the beginning by the user.

Is creating the layout at runtime in Java the only solution? I would like to keep the application views separated from the application logic. The questions will be of multiple types (multi-choice, radio buttons, drop-downs...)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template for each of the question types in xml and then just inflate that at runtime and fill in the correct information.  This will allow you to redesign the look without having to touch code.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind, I did not know it was possible in Android. Any useful link with an example? Cheers

Comment: "...and fill in the correct information...". That is the point. How can I change the default attributes???

Comment: You can use the LayoutInflater to inflate any layout file and then just add that to your existing view.  Here is a tutorial on how to get started: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/06/android-layoutinflater-turorial.html